# Executor Service invokeAll

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am fairly new to the callable interface. I have some code which I can't get to compile at the moment and just need some help on why....

```
public List<String> getNonPingableRegisters (Collection<RegisterReplicationSynchTime> nonReplicatingRegisters) throws IOException {

    int nThreads = 15;
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

    Collection<Callable<PingTask>> pingTasks = new ArrayList<Callable<PingTask>>(nonReplicatingRegisters.size());
    for (RegisterReplicationSynchTime nonReplicatingRegister : nonReplicatingRegisters) {
        pingTasks.add(new PingTask(nonReplicatingRegister.getRegisterName()));
    }

    List<Future<String>> taskResults = es.invokeAll(pingTasks);
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Future<String> taskResult : taskResults) {
        try {
            String output = taskResult.get();
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(output) ) {
                results.add(output);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle accordingly
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // handle accordingly          
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Where PingTask is ...

```
public class PingTask implements Callable<String> {

    private String hostname = null;

    public PingTask(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

        public String call() {
            Socket socket = null;
            boolean reachable = false;  
            try {                           
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, 139), 1000); //1 sec timeout                     
                reachable = true;
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                }
            }       
            return (reachable ? "" : hostname);
        }

    }
```

The compile error is at ...

```
List<Future<String>> taskResults = es.invokeAll(pingTasks);
```

The method add(Callable) in the type Collection> is not applicable for the arguments (PingTask)    StoreReplicationSynchtimeManagerImpl.java

Not sure what I need to do here to make the call to invokeAll. Would appreciate some help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is not at that line. 
It's at:

```
pingTasks.add(new PingTask(nonReplicatingRegister.getRegisterName()));
```

Your collection is of Callable where as your PingTask class implements Callable. Change the collection to:

```
Collection<Callable<String>>
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your mistake:

```
Collection<Callable<PingTask>> pingTasks = new ArrayList<Callable<PingTask>>(nonReplicatingRegisters.size());
```

`PingTask` implements `Callable<String>`, not `Callable<PingTask>`. You need to declare your list as `Collection<PingTask>` or `Collection<Callable<String>>`.

Comment: that's the thing. Even when I have Collection<PingTask> pingTasks = new ArrayList<PingTask>(nonReplicatingRegisters.size()); I still get The method invokeAll(Collection<Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<PingTask>) StoreReplicationSynchtimeManagerImpl.java

Comment: @Richie So update your post and we'll take another look.

Comment: @Richie, I tried compiling (a derivative of) your code and the only error I'm getting is for an unhandled `InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mis-match.

```
 Collection<Callable<PingTask>> pingTasks = new ArrayList<Callable<PingTask>>
```

But PingTask is declared as

```
public class PingTask implements Callable<String>
```

Change collection as `Collection<PingTask>`

```
pingTasks.add(new PingTask(nonReplicatingRegister.getRegisterName()));
```

will cause compile time error due to `Callable<String>`  type addition